# height in vh (viewport) and max-height in px (pixels)

Tags: css

Is it possible to define height of element where CSS3 tells:

```
if viewport >= 1000px then
      element height: 300px (in pixels)
else if viewport < 1000px
      element height: 30vh (30% of viewport height)
```

So all I want is to have an element that has 30% of viewport but not more than 300px. Is it possible?

This is what I've tested but didn't work:

```
div {
    height: 30vh;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: It does work... See an example with a `100px` limit: http://jsfiddle.net/LtLaf7to/1/

Comment: Does not work for me neither, having a height in vh, max-height has an impact, but not on its children

Comment: Does this only work in some browsers?

Comment: By viewport you mean viewport's height?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no gist to check, I'll make a series of assumptions.

1. The element itself respects the height constraints
2. The elements within the target overflow outside their parents.

**Does adding overflow: hidden to your target element solves the issue?**

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stojanovic/3sjLvfpu/4/)

```
<p>test content</p>

p {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  p {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```